# Codepen prevents p5.dom webcam capture

Tags: p5.js, codepen

I developed some [working code](https://editor.p5js.org/jcoleman/sketches/knrT7O25-) on the p5.js Web editor and wanted to port it to Codepen for further work. Even the following [example](https://p5js.org/examples/dom-video-capture.html) from the processing website [fails to work](https://codepen.io/jpcoleman/pen/ExYzNVj):

```
let capture;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(390, 240);
  capture = createCapture(VIDEO);
  capture.size(320, 240);
  //capture.hide();
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  image(capture, 0, 0, 320, 240);
  filter(INVERT);
}
```

When I try to run the code, I enable my webcam which turns on for about 2 seconds before shutting down. No image is captured. There is no error message in the console. I have found some pens that do have working webcams (and others that seem to have the same issue), but none that I saw tried to do it through the [p5.dom library](https://p5js.org/reference/#/libraries/dom).

Is this a known issue? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Can you put together a simpler example? I don't know what your working code is supposed to do, so it's hard to debug it. Can you get a more basic example working?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Sorry -- I should have started with a [mcve]. The issue seems to be codepen/p5.dom interaction rather than a JavaScript bug. The working code isn't directly relevant (beyond the fact that it *is* working in the p5.js web editor) but is an experiment in reproducing with webcam images the famous (in cryptography) [linux-penguin example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) which visually shows the weakness of ECB block cipher mode